# Getting This site can't be reached after doing Manual Proxy settings in wifi on Andoid/IOS device

Tags: android, debug, ios, debugger

I am trying to do proxy configuration in Redmi Note 7 Android 9. I have connected my Macbook and Device to the same wifi network, after doing manual configuration for Proxy IP address:192.168.XX.XX, Port 8888 I am not able to the browser itself. Getting error message that I am offline on Google chrome.

I have also tried installing the SSL root certificate in mac and tried to install the same in Android phone as well as I was not able to launch chls.pro/ssl in my device.

Not able to install .pem certificate also, so converted into .cert and installed in device. Does anyone know how to troubleshoot it?

Comment: I don't suppose you're using secure DNS or DNS over TLS? It may not be resolving correctly.

Comment: I am not sure what to comment on this, but I can see that Android 9 supports DNS over TLS. Assuming it is not resolving correctly how can I troubleshoot it?

Comment: Disable secure DNS in settings and try again?  Otherwise it's possible the DNS on your proxy server broken or iptables/firewall is blocking blocking port 8888.

Comment: Installing the SSL root certificate on Android is useless since Android 7 (without root permissions). See also [this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/219280/2241) especially the part about HTTPS at the end.

Comment: @BoeroBoy DNS settings are disabled for my proxy server, I tried with different ports as well. But nothing works.

Comment: @Robert Thanks for sharing this info, but my issue is not specific to fetch network debug logs. I am not able to access internet at all after configuring the Manual Proxy settings in my Android device.

Comment: Looks like you should test if your Android device can send data to your MacBook at all. A lot of Wifi routers disable Wifi-to-Wifi data transmission. You have to make sure it is enabled in Wifi (router) settings and then use Chrome on Android and go to neverssl.com to make sure the proxy works at all (plain HTTP site so there is no certificate problem).